# Jquery script in php foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, loops, append

I have php foreach loop, where .data_fromCity contains different value for each element. Each item has form with input. What i want to do is to get EACH $fromCity variable value and append it to that input.

```
<?php foreach( $rows as $row ) : { ?>

<div class="data_fromCity"><?php echo $fromCity; ?></div>
<form><input type="text" name="cityinput" value=""></form>

<?php } ?>
```

I was thinking about adding to that loop something like that, but it adds text of all php items in one line for all items.

```
<script> $("input[name='cityinput']").val($('.data_fromCity').text()); </script>
```

It should be easy in jquery, but i'm not good at jquery :) Thanks for any help!

The source code what is rendered on frontend is:

```
<div class='wrapper'>

    <div class="data_fromCity">London</div>
    <form><input type="text" name="cityinput" value=""></form>

    <div class="data_fromCity">Rome</div>
    <form><input type="text" name="cityinput" value=""></form>

    <div class="data_fromCity">Paris</div>
    <form><input type="text" name="cityinput" value=""></form>

    <div class="data_fromCity">Madrid</div>
    <form><input type="text" name="cityinput" value=""></form>

</div>
```

Comment: You can't do `<input type="text" name="cityinput" value="<?php echo $fromCity; ?>">` ?

Comment: @Drakes why? it is php loop and i'm getting that variable for each item.

Comment: Where does $fromCity come from? In your loop it looks like it will always stay the same.

Comment: @Drakes i'm getting it from custom field ($fromCity= $row['from_city'];) Forgot to add it to code. So it's different for each item.

Comment: Then just do it all in PHP like in my previous comment. Why even use jQuery? What am I missing? You want to copy the text in `<div class="data_fromCity">` to the value of the `<input>` just below it, right?

Comment: @Drakes sorry... just now understood that was your solution :) sorry. The thing is that the form is from Wordpress contact form plugin, so i'm trying to solve it with jquery as the form code is dynamically generated by plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With wrapper it will be easier:

```
<?php foreach( $rows as $row ) : { ?>

    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class="data_fromCity"><?php echo $fromCity; ?></div>
      <form><input type="text" name="cityinput" value=""></form>
    </div>

<?php } ?>


<script type='text/javascript'>

    $.each($('.wrapper'), function(){
        $this = $(this);
        text = $this.find('.data_fromCity').text();
        $this.find('input[name="cityinput"]').val(text);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work :( it is also getting all data_fromcity values as one big word in each item input.

Comment: show me pls, what you get in <div class="data_fromCity"><?php echo $fromCity; ?></div>  how looks $fromCity ?

Comment: $fromCity = is f.e. London. So i'm getting f.e. 4 items where i have fromcity variable = some city and form input for each of item. So 4 divs with city, 4 inputs where that city should append to.

Comment: pls, just add to your answer your part with it from results html page.

Comment: just edited my first comment in this question see part "The source code what is rendered on frontend is"

Comment: you wrong use wrapper - every div+input have to wrapped! i edit ans

Comment: oh, ok, Not sure why it's still not working, but i will try to recheck my code and will come back very very soon :)

Comment: mb your code wrong, because you ahve 4 inputs with same 'name' - what your final goal?

Comment: just checked my code, i'm still was not using wrapper for each item... Now it work just perfect. Thank you very much for the solution!  I was trying to solve it all the day!!! Finally :)

Comment: @MIC glad to help you, gl hf.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a wrapper. You can do it in 3 lines.

```
$inputs = $('input[name="cityinput"]');
$('.data_fromCity').each(function(i, obj) {
    $($inputs.get(i)).val( $(obj).text() );
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ya3vewgo/

Comment: You selected an answer just 50 seconds before I could post this, but try this out just for fun so you don't have to add any more HTML

Comment: yeah that works perfectly too :) Thank you very much. You guys are awesome. So much help and so fast problem solving here.

Comment: Upvote when you get two more rep then k ... and now you can. ;)